# How to create a custom entity by a workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Please note - the question is **does not** regard how to *create an instance of an entity* but rather how to *create a definition of an entity*.

On the exam I've seen a question about how to create a custom entity. The options were:

1. by workflow execution
2. by solution import
3. by dialog run
4. by solution alternation
5. by data import

The obviously right ones are #2 and #4. The apparently wrong ones are #3 and #5. Furthermore, I'd say that #1 is incorrect too. However, according to the guide, it's correct.

Is it possible to create an entity by executing a workflow? How?! (If it's not, I'd like to have that stated explicitly in an answer.)

Comment: with "the guide" you mean the official MOC?

Comment: @GuidoPreite Someone stuck a bunch of questions/answers into my inbox. I believe those are based on the MOC. However, I haven't found this particular piece of information so I'm a bit confused. Suggestions?

Comment: I never saw an entity created by a workflow. Although it is theoretically possible (using a custom workflow activity), the privilege to create an entity (the minimum maybe is System Customizer?) is mandatory, so in my opinion the #1 question is wrong

Comment: @GuidoPreite Agreed. Please post the contents of your comment as a reply so I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never saw an entity created by a workflow.

Although it is theoretically possible (using a custom workflow activity), the privilege to create a custom entity is mandatory, so in my opinion the #1 answer is wrong.

Note:

The minimum security role to create a custom entity is `System Customizer` with `Read`, `Create`, `Write` privileges on `Entity`, as reported here (Task `Create custom entities`):

http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/dynamics/crm-customer-center/permissions-required-for-customization-tasks.aspx

and as reported inside the comments:

> Modification of the entity attributes, form, views, or messages
>   require additional privileges.

Comment: Agreed.  Also I can't think of a reasonable situation where you would want to dynamically create entity customizations.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to create a new entity from the Import Data Wizard therefore I suggest that point 5 from your question is the third correct answer.  These are the steps that I followed to create a new entity from Import Data Wizard:

1. Select the csv file to import.  Ensure that the name of the file does not match the name of an entity in the system e.g. NotAnEntity.csv
2. Select a data map (I chose Default but I doubt it matters which is chosen)
3. On the Map Record Types page select 'Create New' from the 'Record Types' drop down.  Note that this page will not show if the name of the csv matches the name of an entity in CRM or if you are trying to import an xml file that was exported from CRM with the option 'Make this data available for re-importing by including required column heading' selected
4. You'll be prompted to provide a name and plural name for the new entity
5. On the Map Fields page for each field select 'Create New Field' from the 'CRM Fields' drop down
6. Complete the wizard and the new entity will be created and populated with the data from the csv

Comment: Was able to successfully create an Entity and related field from *Setting > Imports > Import Data* in MS Dynamics CRM 2015 Online. Useful technique !

Comment: Its a good technique.. never thought one can create a custom entity using the import data wizard.. but I was wrong.. The only thing is I doubt if this is not configured as a correct answer in CRM exam, then we may lose some score!!

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this exam and was stumped on this question as well.

Researched all the options and I think Data Import is the 3rd option as you are able to create a new entity when using the Import Data Wizard just like you can for new fields.